# Execução paralela

Tags: c#, thread, assincronismo

Tenho um processo que fica em execução na minha aplicação para controle. Esse processo é executado dentro de um timer.

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // bloco de instruções 1

    // bloco de instruções 2
}
```

O que acontece é que o processamento do bloco de instruções 1 acaba sendo demorado, e o bloco de instruções 2 acaba sendo 'refém' dessa demora.

Gostaria de que enquanto o bloco de instruções 1 fosse executado, o bloco de instruções 2 também fosse executado, quantas vezes ele for chamado pelo `timer`.

> O código executado no bloco 2 não depende do bloco 1.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode criar um array de tarefas, e utilizar o comando `Task.WaitAll` para aguardar todas terminarem.

```
var tarefas = new List<Task>()
{
    Task.Run(() => {
        // Bloco de código 1
    }),
    Task.Run(() => {
        // Bloco de código 2
    })
};

Task.WaitAll(tarefas.ToArray());
```